# Filter data frame based on paired combinations of variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame, `ex_data` in the example below, that lists participant id, a group identifier, and some value. I then have a second data frame that indicates particular observations that need to be removed (`remove_data` in the below example). Is there a way to use **dplyr** or other **tidyverse** functions to filter out these combinations? In my efforts below, I end up filtering out all record for the indicated participants, rather than just the data for when the participant was in that specific group. I'm able to get the desired output using a for loop, which I've also included for reference.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
#> Loading tidyverse: tibble
#> Loading tidyverse: tidyr
#> Loading tidyverse: readr
#> Loading tidyverse: purrr
#> Loading tidyverse: dplyr
#> Conflicts with tidy packages ----------------------------------------------
#> filter(): dplyr, stats
#> lag():    dplyr, stats

set.seed(1234)
ex_data <- data_frame(
  id = rep(sample(1:100, 10), 2),
  group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 10),
  score = rnorm(20)
)
ex_data
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>       id group       score
#>    <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1    12     a  0.50605589
#>  2    62     a -0.57473996
#>  3    60     a -0.54663186
#>  4    61     a -0.56445200
#>  5    83     a -0.89003783
#>  6    97     a -0.47719270
#>  7     1     a -0.99838644
#>  8    22     a -0.77625389
#>  9    99     a  0.06445882
#> 10    47     a  0.95949406
#> 11    12     b -0.11028549
#> 12    62     b -0.51100951
#> 13    60     b -0.91119542
#> 14    61     b -0.83717168
#> 15    83     b  2.41583518
#> 16    97     b  0.13408822
#> 17     1     b -0.49068590
#> 18    22     b -0.44054787
#> 19    99     b  0.45958944
#> 20    47     b -0.69372025


remove_data <- data_frame(
  id = sample(ex_data$id, 3),
  group = sample(c("a", "b"), 3, replace = TRUE)
)
remove_data
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      id group
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1    62     b
#> 2    97     a
#> 3    60     b

# Current efforts
ex_data %>%
  filter(!(id %in% remove_data$id & group %in% remove_data$group))
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#>       id group       score
#>    <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1    12     a  0.50605589
#>  2    61     a -0.56445200
#>  3    83     a -0.89003783
#>  4     1     a -0.99838644
#>  5    22     a -0.77625389
#>  6    99     a  0.06445882
#>  7    47     a  0.95949406
#>  8    12     b -0.11028549
#>  9    61     b -0.83717168
#> 10    83     b  2.41583518
#> 11     1     b -0.49068590
#> 12    22     b -0.44054787
#> 13    99     b  0.45958944
#> 14    47     b -0.69372025


# Desired output
for (i in 1:nrow(remove_data)) {
  ex_data <- ex_data %>%
    filter(!(id == remove_data$id[i] & group == remove_data$group[i]))
}
ex_data
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#>       id group       score
#>    <int> <chr>       <dbl>
#>  1    12     a  0.50605589
#>  2    62     a -0.57473996
#>  3    60     a -0.54663186
#>  4    61     a -0.56445200
#>  5    83     a -0.89003783
#>  6     1     a -0.99838644
#>  7    22     a -0.77625389
#>  8    99     a  0.06445882
#>  9    47     a  0.95949406
#> 10    12     b -0.11028549
#> 11    61     b -0.83717168
#> 12    83     b  2.41583518
#> 13    97     b  0.13408822
#> 14     1     b -0.49068590
#> 15    22     b -0.44054787
#> 16    99     b  0.45958944
#> 17    47     b -0.69372025
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why not use `anti_join` instead of `filter`?

```
dplyr::anti_join(ex_data, remove_data)

Joining, by = c("id", "group")
# A tibble: 17 x 3
      id group       score
   <int> <chr>       <dbl>
 1    47     b -0.69372025
 2    99     b  0.45958944
 3    22     b -0.44054787
 4     1     b -0.49068590
 5    97     b  0.13408822
 6    83     b  2.41583518
 7    61     b -0.83717168
 8    12     b -0.11028549
 9    47     a  0.95949406
10    99     a  0.06445882
11    22     a -0.77625389
12     1     a -0.99838644
13    83     a -0.89003783
14    61     a -0.56445200
15    60     a -0.54663186
16    62     a -0.57473996
17    12     a  0.50605589
```